# How to query object data type in Elastic search?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

We have a elastic record. For a single record, we might have status for TA,AI,ML,BL and few like below.

```
Record1 : { status.VI : "A",
 status.BL : "A",
 id:"110716",
 pe:"1344"},

Record2 : {
  status.TA : "A",
  status.QL : "A",
  id:"310716",
  pe:"3344"
 }
Record3 : {
  status.TA : "I",
  status.QL : "I",
  id:"410716",
  pe:"4344"
 }
Record4 : {
  status.BL : "A",
  status.QL : "I",
  id:"510716",
  pe:"5344"
 }
```

I have lot of records which might not contain all of them. For some records, only for QL and TA status will be there. For some records BL might only have status. I have to query and fetch the result which has the status only "I" for whatever the value is ( TA,BL,QL..)

For example, in the above records I need to get only Record 3 as it is having the staus "I" for whatever the value has present.

```
     "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "status.TA": "I",
                        "status.QL": "I",
                        "status.ML": "I",
                        "status.BL": "I"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

If I try to give like above, it is not working and in all the records QL,ML,BL,TA need no be there. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A match query does not support multiple fields.
There can be many ways to solve this problem. A mulit match query for example:

```
 GET test_index/_search
     {
       "query": {
         "multi_match": {
           "query": "I",
           "fields": ["status.TA","status.QL","status.ML","status.BL"]
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But there could be only one  like "Status.QL" or Status.TA also, In that case it wont work know? Please suggest

Comment: Did you try running the query? It will work fine even if there is a field missing from the document.